# Decoding this PHP?

Tags: php, encoder

Okso I have some PHP that I'm working with for a client. The last guy to make his site encoded all his PHP to make it difficult for guys like me to come in and make changes. I have no idea what this is.

Ok so it started off as this:

```
<?php $OOO000000=urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63%6f%5f%74%6e%64');$OOO0000O0=$OOO000000{4}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{5};$OOO0000O0.=$OOO000000{2}.$OOO000000{10}.$OOO000000{13}.$OOO000000{16};$OOO0000O0.=$OOO0000O0{3}.$OOO000000{11}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO0000O0{7}.$OOO000000{5};$OOO000O00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO000000{7}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{15};$O0O000O00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{1}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{14};$O0O000O0O=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{11};$O0O000O00=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{3};$O0O00OO00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{16};$OOO00000O=$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8};$OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;$OO00O0000=0xa68;eval($OOO0000O0('JE8wMDBPME8wMD0kT09PMDAwTzAwKCRPT08wTzBPMDAsJ3JiJyk7JE8wTzAwT08wMCgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDB4NTU0KTskT08wME8wME8wPSRPT08wMDAwTzAoJE9PTzAwMDAwTygkTzBPMDBPTzAwKCRPMDAwTzBPMDAsMHgxN2MpLCdmaFY2THhOT01GUlgwZXZjK3lTOEhXdHNZcUpuUUNQVEJacGszb0VnQXU5YjI1MW1Jai9yYTRHemxkRFU3S3dpPScsJ0FCQ0RFRkdISUpLTE1OT1BRUlNUVVZXWFlaYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Ky8nKSk7ZXZhbCgkT08wME8wME8wKTs='));return;?>~DFLKc06hc06hc064rCOFTQEWInNxkqSBgs4KNSHjxs47gXVMgMpl38aKc0L7I8rfIXpMgMpI38aKc06fI0L7IRVyc8a7I06fI0L7AFL7I8rfI8a7I0VB38rfI0L7I8rfIXVyc8rfI8rfI06fuXVCEJxYG8OZv8a4NHoBIqsqkRzo8vLZsCOeqQHu1HHe+WLFJQN2rnaWg+sHdYkM40t4FJpK/Y8yOPEj3yxHzSzCucSQ2FaxV+ayxy3CMSHuX8L4v84hyHoeHWWqstxoJYtFkqNWEqGZuJE52ntdmQOx/Qzy4CgClPsAI08Mre6HGerBdR/7gRS3uvGqknNKrqSB38rfI0L7I8rfIR85oCEx2RVyc8rfI8rfI8rfuvI==VEe2YserMNxrnHjunE2RPIurCNxaJt0BqgW1YzyunGlBYzFoYsyoHGWZQEeAWsF2MVB3nzFuqGo1YtjWQEIuVg2RFNK/JtCunEx2WsF2M6aBCOFunSB3nzFuqGo1YtjWQEIuvIA3Yt4DWsF2+EoaQ/fKMOhZQgeoszW/nVB3nzFuqGo1YtjWQEIuvIA3Yt4DHGeAqt4oM6aBFNx5PoW/nLFuCOenFzekJNW5qSCCvIA3Yt4DSNKrCVfKMVyZnsuWQEjVJsyrt/CAnzeaF4aUVpyZnsuLnG4ZJtlBcSf3Yt4DHGeAqt4oXpQDX/7gXpyZnsuMnzeavIuIYsFrqWKrCOMAFNx5PoW/nLFuCOenFzx4qsFdF4a2FNx5PohZQEx5Q/3UVpyZnsu+YsyA+EoaQ/fKMNWlQNjmqNHAF/7gXVyZnsuWQEjVJsyrt/CIYsyAF4auvIA3Yt4DHNxaJLx/QExdM6aBYsF/Ys3AR82RqEK/qtxkJVfAFNx5PohZCNZVJsyrMNxrMVyIYsyA+EoaRShUVpyIYsyA+EoaM6aBCOFunSB3QNxaJLFuCV3UVEoEMVZrCtFrCOMAFOhZCNZVJs+20VIrRSfKcSfgQEWEF/3BPIA3Yt4DHNx/Yt4rt/C/qtYgsSfKMVyIYsyA+EoavIuKqtjrqShuqpfAMtW5QOydRVyIYsyA+EoaRS3BPIA3Yt4DHNxaJLx/QExdt4aBcSf3QNxaJLFuC62RT+uKVpyZnsu+YsFZnsenFzhZCNBgsSfKMNo5QNjmqNHAF/7gXVyZnsu+YsyA+sF/Ys3uvIA3Yt4DHNxaJVfKMVZuQzeoCVB3Yt4DHNx/Yt4rt/CIYsyAF4auMVYEMtW5QOydRVyZnsu+YsFZnsenFzhZCNBgsS3uVk7gX/Q1FNx5PohZQEx5Q42gQNxaJVCCM6ABF/7gvIA3Yt4DHEWEM6aBRNorQGWaRVyZnsu+YsFZnsenFzFoqpCCRSfEFpxonshaPSB3Yt4DHNx/Yt4rt/C/qtYgsS3uVk7gX/Q1FNx5PohZQEx5Q42gQEWEF4aBvpfgFr2RFNx5PohZQEx5QaK4CVfKMNx/QExdRV3UVpyZnsu+YsFZnsecCsynFGooF4aBcSfAJserqs+AFNx5PohZQEx5Q42gJtHgsS3BFpYZqt4ICO3AFNx5PohZQEx5Q42gJtHgsS3uVk73Yt4DHNx/Yt4rt/CuqSCCM6ABF4WHykBgvIA3CNo5qseaYsfBcShaJt4oRV3UVpy/Ytd3nG48qtemnEyrM6aBQEx1qVB4X60IR82RFNx5PohZQEx5QaK4Cx2gQto3F4aBcSf3CNo5qseaYsfBXSy/Ytd3nG48qtemnEyrvIA3Yt4DHNx/Yt4r8zWat/CrQpCCM6aBRNorQGWaRVyZnsu+YsFZnsenFze/F4auMVYEMtW5QOydRVyZnsu+YsFZnsenFze/F4auR+AiFNx5PohZQEx5Q42gQzMgsSfDMVQgvIA3Yt4DHNx/Yt4r8zWat/CbqsoznzF3Q/CCM6aBRNorQGWaRVyZnsu+YsFZnsenFG5oPsCmQEyrF4auMVYEMtW5QOydRVyZnsu+YsFZnsenFG5oPsCmQEyrF4auR+AiFNx5PohZQEx5Q42gJGWdCGK/qO0gsSfDMVQgvIA3Yt4DyNWrCNo1YsyunGlBcSf3Yt4DyNK5Yto1MVl3Yt4DHNxaJVf1FNx5PoFoqk2RFNx5P3yoQzyunExaJtK1MVlKMVQiF/dACOyIsGF4Jtj3szx4qsFdRVyZnsu+YsFZnsecCs+uvIu/qsy4QElBFNx5P3yoQzyunExaJtK1vIuKVEq4nEeaJtK1MNe2Jteb+GK4ng+BRVy2JtdbRShUVpyAJsyknzW1CNW/M6aBF/l1X/Q1FNjunE2BXpQmJNoaYGK4ngyoQpdZQGagvIuoYGZmMVF6nzW1CNW/MLqunNHDMNZuCNemCtdaqsMpvIuknNWZQgeaYsykYteAqSBuvIA3nNKkJaemCtdaM6aB062RJtYBRNqunNWTqsZuQzyrRVyAJsyknzW1CNW/RS3BPIA3qEBBcShEnzhonpB3JNoaYGK4ngyoQpIgQp2gR82RCGZunNHA0S3BPIuuqpfAqEjmYG2AFNqAXLjc+a5TyWBuRShUVpypCtqEqsMBcShkJNKIRNq/qtx3RVyEJVjEJtjoQGoDqSB3JNoaYGK4ngyoQp3uR82RFNF4qEqoQp2bvIu/qsCunE+AFNqAR82RqgC/JsyoRVyEJVI3YgWEqEW/R82RqEq2CseARVyEJV3UVEqaQgW1YGxaqSB3qEB2qgyonNIAFNqARS3UVEq2nGebRVyEJVj08aeXs4WvR82RYgFoYt2UVg4onOeoMO2RFNjmYG56nzW1CV2bvIurnNWoQVBjR82RT+uuqpfAFNjmYG56nzW1CVfwcSf4RShUVEF/qtxbvIuKVgaRTtW2QGHBPIA3qEBBcShEnzhonpB3JNoaYGK4ngyoQpIgC/2gR82RqgC/JsyoRVyEJVIp0SMuvIA3YgWEqEW/cSMjMk2RT+uEYGjmQGHAFNqAR82RT+uKVpyZQG48qtx/YGZWQEIBcShZQG40JtdbvkukQEWZCNW8qtx/YGZWQEIAFN4dnNo1JGyoQz+uvIAUalVnRPIq
```

I then decoded it into this:

```
<?php $O000O0O00 = $OOO000O00($OOO0O0O00, 'rb');
$O0O00OO00($O000O0O00, 0x554);
$OO00O00O0 = $OOO0000O0($OOO00000O($O0O00OO00($O000O0O00, 0x17c), 'fhV6LxNOMFRX0evc+yS8HWtsYqJnQCPTBZpk3oEgAu9b251mIj/ra4GzldDU7Kwi=', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'));
eval($OO00O00O0); ?>
```

However I have not gotten any further. Any idea on how to work with this?

Comment: Must be declaring those variables somewhere.  Pretty funny obfuscation.  Not sure how he did it.

Comment: Who in the right mind would not allow other developers to make changes to the code in the future? It may be easier to just re-implement the code.

Comment: @bozdoz I'm lost right now. I can't find anything anywhere.

Comment: You're missing parts of it. But shouldn't replacing that eval with `print $OO00O00O0;` display all of it?

Comment: @onetrickpony It's an obnoxious multi-stage decoder that decrypts content from the end of the script. So it's not quite as easy as that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ooh, a puzzle! I like puzzles.

This decoder has two stages.

The first one assigns a number of strings, then decodes and evaluates the second stage. Here it is with some of the bad formatting and variable names removed:

```
$map=urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63%6f%5f%74%6e%64');
$base64_decode=$map{4}.$map{9}.$map{3}.$map{5};
$base64_decode.=$map{2}.$map{10}.$map{13}.$map{16};
$base64_decode.=$base64_decode{3}.$map{11}.$map{12}.$base64_decode{7}.$map{5};
$fopen=$map{0}.$map{12}.$map{7}.$map{5}.$map{15};
$fgets=$map{0}.$map{1}.$map{5}.$map{14};
$fgetc=$fgets.$map{11};
$fgets=$fgets.$map{3};
$fread=$map{0}.$map{8}.$map{5}.$map{9}.$map{16};
$strtr=$map{3}.$map{14}.$map{8}.$map{14}.$map{8};
$filename=__FILE__;
$hex_a68=0xa68;
eval($base64_decode(another base64 blob -- the second stage))
```

Each of the strings, besides `$map` and `$filename`, ends up getting assigned its name as contents.

The second stage, which is decoded from a Base64 blob, consists of the second part you already discovered, which I've treated similarly below:

```
$fh = $fopen($filename, 'rb');
$fread($fh, 0x554);
$data = $base64_decode($strtr(
    $fread($fh, 0x17c),
    'fhV6LxNOMFRX0evc+yS8HWtsYqJnQCPTBZpk3oEgAu9b251mIj/ra4GzldDU7Kwi=',
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'
));
eval($data);
```

This reads some encoded data from the current PHP file, modifies it using `strtr()`, Base64 decodes it, then evaluates that. The results of this decoding appear to be somewhat corrupted (possibly you've omitted part of the input?), but include this readable fragment of PHP code:

```
class asmLink
{
static function createSearchUrl ($originalUrl)
{
$originalUrl = trim($originalUrl);
$amzUrlBits = parse_url($originalUrl);
$amzScheme = $amzUrlBits['
```

---

As an aside: Your client would be well advised to consider reading their contract with the previous developer very carefully, and may want to consider legal proceedings — that developer has *deliberately* taken steps to prevent your client from having their site maintained by anyone else.

Comment: Thank you. Very tricky, thought this would be an endless nightmare!